# I want use Mysql Migration Toolkit , Migrating MS SQL to MySQL but can't find Migration Toolkit

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration

I want use Mysql Migration Toolkit to migrate MS SQL to MySQL.

I can't find Migration Toolkit from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

Does anyone have a good suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find the Migration Toolkit any more on the servers of MySQL, 
because they are distributing a new tool for managing and maintaining mysql server called MySQL-Workbench,
that ought to replace the MySQL GUI Tools.

But I've still found the tool you were looking for at http://mysql-gui-tools.softonic.de/ .
So move quick and watch the date of this post.
It's possible that it won't be available there any more in the near future.

PS:
I haven't used these older tools yet, but the mysql workbench.
And it has a lot of cool functionalities like Reverse & Forward Engineering

Answer (score 0):

just down-load tool package and install it

download from here: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html 
choose the suitable one with your window then download and install